# $Q$ is not connected but the following proof shows that $Q$ is connected.

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

$Q$, the set of all rationals is not connected as there exists a partition of open sets $Q=(Q\cap (-\infty, \sqrt 2))\cup (Q\cap (\sqrt 2, \infty))$.

The following proof shows however that $Q$ is connected:

Suppose that $U\subset Q$ is any clopen set. It suffices to show that $U\in\{\emptyset, Q\}$.

$U\subset Q$ is open so there exists open set $V\subset R$ such that $U=V\cap Q$.

$U\subset Q$ is closed so there exists a closed set $V_1\subset R$ such that $U=V_1\cap Q$.

$\emptyset =U-U=(V-V_1)\bigcap Q$. By density of $Q$, since $V-V_1$ is open in $R$, it must be the emptyset. It follows that $V=V_1$.

$V$ is clopen in $R$. Since $R$ is connected, $V=\emptyset$ or $V=R$. It follows that $U\in \{\emptyset, Q\}$. So $Q$ is connected.

Using the same proof, $R\setminus Q$ is connected.

What is wrong in the above proof? Thanks.

Comment: Take a non-trivial set you know to be clopen in $\Bbb Q$ (you have already written down two suitable candidates in your first sentence), and see which step of the proof doesn't apply to it. That's a general approach for finding the flaw in a proof that is known to be faulty, and it usually pans out.

Comment: lol. three answers all at the exact same time more or less

Comment: no idea. Sometimes this happens, the three posts were within a half minute of each other

Comment: Thanks a lot. The error was: $V-V_1=\emptyset\implies V=V_1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$V-V_1=\emptyset$ does not imply $V=V_1$. What if $V\subseteq V_1$?

With your example at the start, we could have $V=(-\infty,\sqrt{2})$ and $V_1:=(-\infty,\sqrt{2}]$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $A=\{1,2,3\}$ and $B=\{1,2,3,4\}$.  Then note that $A-B=\emptyset$ and yet $A\neq B.$